# make command fails over ubuntu 16.04 for thrift server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, thrift, thrift-protocol

I have downloaded apache thrift.

step one move to thrift folder --
and run below commands over terminal

```
1- ./bootstrap.sh
2- ./configure
3- ./configure --without-java
```

below command fails

```
4- make


all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/www/html/thrift'
Making all in compiler/cpp
make[2]: Entering directory '/var/www/html/thrift/compiler/cpp'
Making all in src
make[3]: Entering directory '/var/www/html/thrift/compiler/cpp/src'
/bin/bash ../../../ylwrap thrift/thrifty.yy y.tab.c thrift/thrifty.cc y.tab.h `echo thrift/thrifty.cc | sed -e s/cc$/hh/ -e s/cpp$/hpp/ -e s/cxx$/hxx/ -e s/c++$/h++/ -e s/c$/h/` y.output thrift/thrifty.output -- yacc -d 
../../../ylwrap: line 176: yacc: command not found
Makefile:659: recipe for target 'thrift/thrifty.cc' failed
make[3]: *** [thrift/thrifty.cc] Error 127
make[3]: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/thrift/compiler/cpp/src'
Makefile:1483: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/thrift/compiler/cpp'
Makefile:683: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/www/html/thrift'
Makefile:599: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: "yacc: command not found" seems a pretty clear indication of the problem.  You don't have the `yacc` program, nor any viable alternative, such as `bison`.  I'm sure Ubuntu has at least the latter available, but apparently it is not installed by default.

Comment: thank you for pointing the error, i was not able to get it let me install and retry it